# Data Fetch custom Hook is triggered every state change / render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a custom hook as following

```
export const useFetchLesson = (lesson_id) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const languages = useSelector(state => getDeviceLanguage(state));

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const requestUrl =  "https://school.com/" + lesson_id;
        const res = await fetch(requestUrl, {
          headers: header
        });
        const json = await res.json();
        setResponse(json);
        setIsLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [lesson_id]);

  return { response, error, isLoading };
};
```

Then I am using this custom hook in one of my component as following:

```
const TrueOrFalse = (props) => {
  const [lesson, setLesson] = useState();
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(null);

  let lesson_id = props.route.params ? props.route.params.id : 123;
  const res = useFetchLesson(lesson_id);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (res && res.response !== null)  {
      setLesson(res.response.data);
    }
  }, [res]);

  // then user's actions are set by calling setAnswer() such as
  // eg. <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setAnswer(0)}>
```

I realised that the useFetchLesson is triggered every time I call the setAnswer. API is not called because `lesson_id` is in the dependency list.

How can I make sure useFetchLesson is called only once and not in every render?

Comment: Do you mean to say that your API is called everytime you call setAnswer. Because it shouldn't. If you mean to say that useFetchLesson is triggered on every re-render, then its a expected behavior, however the useEffect within it shouldn't trigger on every re-render

Comment: Previously, I didn't set the `lesson_id` as dependency in `useFetchLesson` and API is called everytime I call setAnswer. However, now that I set the `lesson_id` as dependency, API is not called but when I put console.log at the beginning of the useFetchLesson, that console is logged everytime I call setAnswer.

Comment: That is an expected behavior. You can imagine it like putting a console log directly in functional component.